# How to avoid ssh connection overheads in scp?

Tags: ssh, scp

I am testing the performance of scp command. I want to minimize the overheads for making TCP connection of ssh protocol inside scp.

How can I open the first ssh connection and reuse it over time?

thanks for your help.

// I should have said that one way to achieve it is to zip the files and send it at once, which only works when the files are available all the time. Let's assume then the files are generated in stream fashion in the source side, and I want to send those as early as possible after they are generated.

// Pleaser refer to the link for the answer I found: (How To Reuse SSH Connection To Speed Up Remote Login Process) http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-reuse-openssh-connection/

Comment: it just means your want to send more data together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are copying so many tiny files that the connection overhead comes into play, you could try tar'ing everything up on the fly and sending that instead.

Try something like this:

```
tar zcvf - data | ssh user@server "cat > data.tar.gz"
```

You can drop the `z` if compression isn't desired/helpful too.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, obviously zipping the files and send it at once is a practical solution. I added some more details for the issue, which cannot be resolved by this method.

Comment: in that case i think you can also feed a online stream to `tar` or rather `ssh` directly, depending on the form of your source data.

Comment: Yup, if we had more specifics about how the files show up there's probably a tweak to this that will work.

Comment: Yes. Feeding the online stream to the destination is the problem. I might be able to change the stream producer-side client codes, so that it directly feeds the stream data into the destination over ssh. However, in this scenario let's assume that I have no such accessibility to the client codes and the client dumps out the data as a bunch of files.

Comment: @syko not sure how you want to implement it. if that's the case, given you probably don't have a filename pattern, you may want to use file watcher to watch your folders, and use paramiko to send your files over ssh. all work will be in python though.